# is this plagiarising an economic model

Tags: plagiarism, copyright, economics

I am currently writing an undergraduate economics thesis in collective household behaviour. I have found a paper that uses a mathematical utility model very similar to one I have been working on independently.

I really like the structure the author has used, and their mathematics solves some of the issues I was finding in my own work.

All  of their justifications at each stage of the model align with my own thinking.

If state I am using their model, with slight adaptations, and follow the structure they had originally set out in their justifications at each stage is this plagiarism?

I am not extending their work, if anything I am simplifying it to suit my own needs.

Where is the line drawn between building on work and copying? If I am to use a model very similar to theirs, would this be a waste of space in my paper as it appears the thoughts are not originally my own? However, having found the paper is it dishonest to continue with my work not referencing the extreme similarity to theirs?

Comment: "I am not extending their work, if anything I am simplifying it to suit my own needs." It sounds like you are applying their work to a problem that allows for a simplification of the model. If that is the case, this is absolutely a (possibly valuable) extension of their work and is perfectly fine.

Comment: Plagiarism doesn't care about how you use a model. It cares about whether you take credit for work someone else did. You could copy every aspect of their work perfectly, and it wouldn't be plagiarism as long as you gave them full credit. (It wouldn't be accepted as a thesis, since you didn't do anything, but it wouldn't be plagiarism.)

Answer (score 32):

What you propose is not plagiarism, as long as you carefully cite the source of the material you are using. Clearly indicate what part of the work is yours. Building on previous work is what scholarship is all about.

This sounds like a good use of the literature for an undergraduate thesis.
Check that with your undergraduate advisor. It might not have enough original material for a journal article, but that is not what you are writing.